# Ani Maamin # 10

Tags: tefilla, ikarim

Ani Maamin # 10 has a unique Nusach. After the belief is stated there is a verse to corroborate the belief.

> אֲנִי מַאֲמִין בֶּאֱמוּנָה שְׁלֵמָה.  שֶׁהַבּוֹרֵא יִתְבָּרַךְ שְׁמוֹ
>   יוֹדֵעַ כָּל מַעֲשֵׂה בְנֵי אָדָם וְכָל מַחְשְׁבוֹתָם.  שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר
>   הַיֹּצֵר יַחַד לִבָּם הַמֵּבִין אֶל כָּל מַעֲשֵׂיהֶם

Why is this belief the only one that the author felt a need to corroborate with a verse?

Comment: This isn't the only belief the Rambam corroborated by a verse. It's just the only one whoever authored these poems decided to include a verse with.

Comment: Rambam lists 13 beliefs is in his commentary to sanhedrin http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37945&st=&pgnum=467 The ani maamin's are just a later anonymous poetic adaptation.

Comment: Important note... The op asks why the author did this and not why did the rambam do this.

Comment: @DoubleAA In fact the Rambam cites other verses for this principle, but does not cite the verse cited in Ani Ma'amin.